# host images on sails with no-frontend flag

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, sails.js

I have created sails project with `sails --no-frontend` flag,  now i need to host images inside assets folder, as i know sails will disable assets folder when creating `--no-frontend`, how can i re-enable it, so that i can store and retrieve images.

```
sails new --no-frontend
```

In the sails default project i can view the images in `http://localhost:1337/images/filename.jpg` but cannot view in `sails --no-frontend`

I cannot regenerate sails with

```
sails new
```

as al lot of work has been done with sails no-frontend, is their and fix for this?